# PHONE_STATE receiver not working with context-based receiver

Tags: java, android

I am developing an android app in which I want to get the incoming call number so I have created a context-based `receiver` and registered it in my `MainActivity`. But my receiver is never triggered regardless whether the app is in `foreground` or `background`. I checked Android docs and they mentioned that you should use context-based receivers for `Android 8.0+` but they have not yet made this exception for `PHONE_STATE` broadcast receivers but I am using context-based just to be on the safe side.
This is how I am registering my receiver:

```
private void registerMyReceiver() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Receiver Triggered !!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            };
            IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
            intentFilter.addAction("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE");
            this.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);

        }

    }
```

I am even asking for run-time permissions too:

```
private void grantPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, 0);
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The other way:

```
TelephonyManager systemService = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    if (systemService == null)
        return;
    PhoneStateListener listener = new PhoneStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String phoneNumber) {
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, phoneNumber);
        }
    };

    systemService.listen(listener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

need the permission:

```
android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
```

use the broadcast:

```
<receiver android:name="PhoneStateReceiver">
        <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
            <action android:name="android.telecom.action.DEFAULT_CALL_SCREENING_APP_CHANGED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

in my project.

in code.

```
 IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
  ....//other actions.
```

try this.

hope to help you.

Comment: there is a problem with this one. It won't work when the app is in background or killed. That is why I am using broadcast receiver so that my receiver gets triggered everytime I receive an incoming call whether the app is in background or foreground.

Comment: will this work if the app is killed from Task Manager or the app goes to background?

Comment: android keep live is a problem in the world. you can try this:https://baijiahao.baidu.com/s?id=1655684761750186375&wfr=spider&for=pc